# If $f(3) = 12$ and $f(2.8) = 12.6$. Then approximate $f'(3)$

Tags: calculus

I am new to this site and old to my problem in calculus. I hope, some one will guide.

If $f(3) = 12$ and $f(2.8) = 12.6$. Then approximate $f'(3)$ ?

Please let me know

Comment: hint: $f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ for some small $h$.

Answer (score 2):

Recall the definition of derivative:

$$
f'(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}
$$

> Simply put $h = 0.2$, then: $$f'(3) \sim \frac{f(3 - 0.2) - f(3)}{-0.2} = -3$$

Comment: I really wouldn't write an equal sign here.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
f'(x_1) =
\left.\frac{df}{dx}\right|_{x=x_1} \approx 
\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta x} =
\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1 - x_0} =
\frac{f_1 - f_0}{x_1 - x_0}
$$
Using your two sample points: $(x_0,f_0) = (2.8,12.6)$, $(x_1, f_1)=(3,12)$

Answer (score 0):

The good ol' $$\frac{\mathrm{rise}}{\mathrm{run}}=\frac{-0.6}{0.2}$$ approximates the [slope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope) of $f(x)$.  Since it's taken between $x=2.8$ and $x=3$, this is where the approximation will be the best.